# Jquery sortable group table rows

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I have this HTML:

```
<table border="blue">
     <tbody id="sortable2">
         <tr class="individual1">
             <td>
                 <tr>
                     <td>1</td>
                 </tr>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="individual2">
             <td>
                 <tr>
                     <td>2</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>2.5</td>
                 </tr>
             </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

and this script part:

```
<script>
$('#sortable2').sortable();
</script>
```

Right now I can sort them, each value.
So, pretty easy. But I want to be able to sort both  individuals seperately.  So I could kinda sort #individual1 (value 1) and #individual2 (values 2 and 2.5) without changing HTML design. Is it possible?
I have googled, but I never saw this design example or solution.